# Why is $\,f(x)=x+\cos(x)$ one-to-one?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone explain to me why $\,f(x)=x+cos (x)$ is one-to-one function?

First I found its first derivative and deduced that it is an increasing function ($1:1$). How can I find its inverse $\,f^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: It is better to ask a new question, than deeply change the existing one. Please observe that the answers are meaningless now.

Comment: The inverse is just what it is: $f^{-1}(y)$ is the unique $x$ such that $y=x+\cos x$.

Answer (score 4):

$f'(x)=1-\sin x\geq0$ (in fact $>0$ instead of isolated points). Hence $f$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: This is what I would call ATtuning to the needs of the asker!

Comment: YA.i just thought of this also,thanks anyway. But how to find (f^-1)(x)?any method?

Comment: how about f^-1(1)?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = x + \cos(x)$.

We need to show that $f(x) = f(y)$ implies that $x = y$.

$$f(x) = f(y) \Longrightarrow x + \cos(x) = y + \cos(y) \Longrightarrow \cos(x) - \cos(y) = y - x$$
$$\Longrightarrow -2\sin(\frac{x}{2} - \frac{y}{2})\sin(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{y}{2}) = y - x \Longrightarrow \sin(\frac{x}{2} - \frac{y}{2})\sin(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{y}{2}) = \frac{x}{2} - \frac{y}{2}$$
$$\Longrightarrow x = y.$$

QED.

Comment: The last implication is not really obvious as your $\Rightarrow$ seems to suggest.